# How to cut part of line?

Tags: grep, awk, inxi

I need to cut line in specific moment, I want to display GPU name, but only name, nothing else.

inxi -Gx | grep Device showing:

```
Device-2: NVIDIA GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] vendor: Dell driver: nouveau
```

I want it to show something like this

```
NVIDIA GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M]
```

How to cut this to show only name? Is there a way to print range, in this case from word Device to word vendor.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the example output of `inxi -Gx | grep Device` and the expected output, [formatted as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). This question is about shell programming / text processing and not specifically related to Ubuntu, so it might better fit on https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: Thanks for your update, however, please check also: "*[...] and the expected output, [formatted as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).*"

Comment: It gives output: Graphics: Device-1 Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics driver: i915

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tryt to do it this way:

```
inxi -Gx | sed -n 's/.*Device-.*: \(.*\) vendor.*/\1/p'
```

Comment: Yes, thats it! Thank you very much. Can you describe how this works? This command

Comment: Sure.
1.  -n param suppresses automatic printing of pattern space(no auto output from sed command)
2. sed is looking for this pattern `.*Device-.*: \(.*\) vendor.*`
3. `/\1/` - sed replaces all the matched line to the first match group (a part of pattern in brackets `(.*\)`)
4. `/p` param in the end prints the current pattern space( print matched lines)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
D=$(inxi -Gx | grep Device)

if [[ $D =~ ^Device-2:([[:print:]]*)vendor:([[:print:]]*)driver:([[:print:]]*)$ ]]
then
  echo "Found Device: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
  echo "Did not find device"
fi
```

Comment: It gives me error
``` syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then") ```

Comment: What version of bash are you using? (`bash --version`)

Comment: 5.0.3. it should work on newer bash?

Comment: It does work with 5.1.4(1). Looking back at the change log regexp matching and BASE_REMATCH *may* be new as of 5.1.

Comment: I can't update bash, its says its newest possible :/

Comment: try add `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Its on the first line of script

Comment: maybe you missed semicolon `]]; then`

Comment: I just realized I have a RaspberryPI with bash 5.0.3(1). It works there as well. Are you sure you entered the `if [[ ... ]]` line correctly? If so, try adding `set -x` to the beginning of the script - the output then may provide a clue.

Answer (score 0):

```
inxi -Gx | grep -oi nv.*]
```

```
inxi -Gx | awk '/Device/{print $2,$3,$4,$5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

`inxi -Gx | grep Device | cut -d ':' -f 2 | sed 's/ vendor//'`

This `cut`s the output into fields using ":" as a delimiter, then it gives you the second field. Use sed then to strip the specific word off the end.

If you know the length then you can cut a range using `cut`, see `man cut` for details.

Comment: I think, that just using `-G` will strip the vendor part of the string?